# Posting data with jQuery in Wordpress succeeds, but fails with FormData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, file-upload

I want to upload a file using jQuery/Ajax in my Wordpress plugin. The javascript to PHP call works. So the wiring etc. works. But as soon as I  post the formData, necessary to post the files, I don't reach the PHP function any more.

The javascript,

```
        var doesntWork = new FormData();
        doesntWork.append('file', 'a name');

        var withthisItWorks = 'text'

        var data = {
            'action': 'emfi_file_upload',
            'data': doesntWork
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                jQuery('#emfi-message').html(`<span style="color: green;">Respons: ${response}</span>`);
            }
        });
```

The PHP function just returns a string answer:

```
function emfi_file_upload_callback() {
    echo 'Yes, in the callback';
    wp_die();
}
```

When I put the plain text in my data object I get answer from the PHP function. When I put the formData in, there is no answer. I've tried a lot of examples on the internet, but it boils down to this every time. Adding contentType: false and processData: false,  as was mentioned somewhere else, didn't help. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All fields that are being sent must be in the formdata object.
Additionally for FormData to work with jQuery.ajax, `processData` and `contentType` have to be set to false.

```
    var doesWork = new FormData();
    doesWork.append('file', someFile);
    doesWork.append('action', 'emfi_file_upload');
  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data: doesWork,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery('#emfi-message').html(`<span style="color: green;">Respons: ${response}</span>`);
        }
    });
```